# Import XML from SQL server to Microsoft Visio

Tags: sql, xml, export, visio, sql-execution-plan

I have been trying to figure out how to import an XML file of the an execution plan of a query from SQL server to Microsoft Visio. However, simply creating the XML file and attempting to open it using Visio is not possible. It gives an error of the form "import file does cont contain recognised schema".

Has anyone ever attempted such a task and been successful? any help/advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You need to get the execution plan in the picture format right ?

Comment: Visio cannot read sql execution plans. Why don't you use MS SQL Server Management Studio to view them?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I know SQL server has the graphical option for the exec plan but in order to allow less familiar users of SQL to view the data (for reports for example), I tried to export it to MS Visio as I assumed it would allow for a more clear image. Thanks again